# VS2012 Master page not rendering changes to the stylesheet declaration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to make a web application using asp.net 4.0 and VS 2012 and for some reason my style sheet declarations are stock to the first version of the site were they weren't inside a folder. now that they are inside a folder, the declarations are still rendering and pushing to the browser as:

```
 <link href="global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Whereas they should be (and are inside VS):

```
 <link href="style/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I really don't know whats going on, am I doing something wrong? I have built, rebuilt, and clean the solution as well as pressing the refresh button (the button, f5, control f5 in IE9, Firefox, and chrome) fifty times.

Comment: Please add the code that generates the link

Comment: there is no code, its static html declaration. The second line (above) is whats there in the master page the first is what is in the browser's source.

Comment: Probably you have a build problem. Try to clean and build your project.

Comment: ok, so I fixed the issue. It was odd, I turned off my computer and back on, it was still doing the same thing. I turned it off again and back on and it magically fixed the problem. I think this is definitely a VS2012 bug. I think I'm gonna report it. Thanks for your time buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. It was a browser caching issue. In IE go to Tools | Internet Options | General Tab. Click on Browsing history "Settings". Set it to "Check for new version of stored pages" to "Every time I visit the page".

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to caching in the browser. What I do when developing web sites is disable the browser cache. Then every time it will load the modified files.

In Google chrome you can use Incognito Window when testing your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just before I thought I would restart, I tried renaming the style sheet. This solved it for me. Appears to be some caching problem indeed.